# Не запускается приложение после повышение до андроид API 33

Tags: android, android-sdk, xamarin, google-play, xamarin.android

Сталкнулся с проблемой. Гугл оповестил меня что мне срочно нужно поднять таргет сисстему с андроид api 31 до 33. Что я благополучно и сделал. После чего меня начали засыпать письмами пользователи, что у них после обновления приложение не открывается, не просто крашится при открытие, а именно не открывается, пользователь тапает на приложение и ничего не происходит. У меня из физических устройств есть galaxy note 10, xiaomi redmi 7 оба работают, на эмуляторах тоже нет проблем. Ко мне обратились юзеры таких устройств realme 5, honor 8x, xiaomi note 8 pro.
Я когда это были только хонор и реалми я предпологал что проблема с сервисами, но после xiaomi теперь ничего не понимаю.
Есть кто сталкивался?

Comment: манифест android:exported="true" ?

Comment: @Style-7 да. Сейчас вообще есть два телефона польщователя, по скринам "О телефоне" абсолютно одинаковых, всё совпадает и у одного работает у второго нет, тапает и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил "методом тыка", в проекта андроида откатил пакет Xamarin.Forms до 5.0.0.2578.
Почему это происходило ответить не могу, вероятно ошибка в последней ревизии пакета. Баг был очень странный, было два абсолютно идентичных смартфона, одна модель, одна версия андроида, все совпадало и на одном работало, на втором нет.
В консоле гугл я получил такую ошибку, но она мне ничего не прояснила.

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3308)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3457)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2044)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7562)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950).